# Where is the Derby embedded driver?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, derby

I have a Spring Boot project with Gradle that I want to use Derby for. I have the following jars included here (I should only need the first, but I'm trying the second too):

```
implementation("org.apache.derby:derby:10.15.2.0")
implementation("org.apache.derby:derbyclient:10.15.2.0")
```

This actually gives me 3 jars (including the tools) and none have the EmbeddedDriver that Spring wants. What gives?

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:derby:/tmp/nhsta_derby;create=true
```

```
Property: driver-class-name
    Value: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
    Origin: "driverClassName" from property source "source"
    Reason: Failed to load driver class org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
```

This finds nothing:

`find ~/.gradle/caches/ -name 'derby*.jar' -exec jar -tf {} \; | grep EmbeddedDriver`

Comment: I downloaded "db-derby-10.14.2.0-lib.zip" from [here](https://db.apache.org/derby/releases/release-10_14_2_0.cgi). I unzipped it. The file `derby.jar` contains `1952 Fri Apr 06 18:09:22 EDT 2018 org/apache/derby/jdbc/EmbeddedDriver.class`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring Boot doesn't support Derby 10.15 as it requires Java 9 or later and Spring Boot currently supports Java 8 and later. If you allow Spring Boot's dependency management to control the version (by omitting the version when you declare the dependency), you'll use 10.14 where the `org.apache.derby:derby` module contains the expected `EmbeddedDriver` class:

```
implementation("org.apache.derby:derby")
```

Comment: For clarity, is no driver command needed for either embedded or server mode deployed as a spring jpa app?

Comment: What do you mean by "driver command"? This may be better addressed by asking a new question rather than in the comments on an answer.

Answer (score 4):

The `org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.class` is located in `implementation("org.apache.derby:derbytools:10.15.2.0")`.